# How to get the subview's size after viewWillTransitionToSize

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView which is shown by a popover presentation. The UICollectionView contains 16 rows of 10 cells each, and I want the cells to fill out the width of the UICollectionView. I'm trying to adjust the size of each cell in viewWillTransitionToSize but I'm having trouble getting the right values.

How do I get the width of the UICollectionView as it will be *after* the transition?

The problem shows up when switching between 50/50 and 70/30 split screen on an iPad Air 2.

Changing from 70/30 to 50/50 gives me too small cells:

[image: 70/30 correct]

[image: 50/50 incorrect]

Changing from 50/50 to 70/30 gives me cells that are too large:

[image: 50/50 correct]

[image: 70/30 incorrect]

Current code:

```
class ColorPickerCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {


var cellsize:CGSize?;


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if let flowLayout = self.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);

    }

}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 16;
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10;
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell

    let colorView = getColorViewForCell(indexPath, cell: cell);
    cell.contentView.addSubview(colorView);

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = UIView();
    cell.selectedBackgroundView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();

    return cell
}

func getColorViewForCell(indexPath:NSIndexPath, cell:UICollectionViewCell) -> UIView {
    let colorView = UIView();
    colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
    colorView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x + 1, cell.bounds.origin.y + 1, cell.bounds.width - 2, cell.bounds.height - 2);
    colorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    return colorView;
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if self.cellsize == nil {
            let width = CGFloat(collectionView.frame.width / 10);
            cellsize = CGSize(width: width, height: width);
        }

        return self.cellsize!;
}

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    NSLog("viewWillTransitionToSize")
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator);

    //What do I do here?
    self.cellsize //= ???;


    let cView:UICollectionView = self.collectionView!;
    cView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil);


}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and overriding `func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(_ newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool` to return true?

Comment: @MikePollard Thanks for the idea, I'll have to try that this weekend.

Comment: @MikePollard Many thanks for leading me in the right direction. I moved my cell size calculations into the FlowLayout subclass and finally got everything working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New solution, thanks to @MikePollard's comment about subclassing the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

I created a subclass `ColorPickerFlowLayout` which is in its entirety below. I set it as the Collection View's layout and let `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize` return the layout's cell size.

I could then delete `viewWillTransitionToSize` in the UICollectionViewController.

```
import UIKit

class ColorPickerFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

  private var cellSize:CGSize? = nil
  var previousBounds: CGRect? = nil

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
     super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  func getCellSize() -> CGSize? {

     return cellSize
  }

  override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {

     if previousBounds == nil || previousBounds!.width != newBounds.width {

        let width = CGFloat(newBounds.width / 10)
        cellSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width)

        previousBounds = newBounds

        self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)

        return true
     } else {

        return false
     }

  }

}
```

Comment: maybe award the bounty to @MikePollard

Comment: @spirographer I gladly would.

Comment: @MikePollard Could you write an answer to this so that I can award you the bounty?